# Ionic/Angular How to add data to list

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array, ionic4

I have an APP that I am working on, at the moment I am working on a section where the user taps on an item that is labelled 'Emergency Contacts'. Then the user is presented a list of 5 empty blocks that each have a label
name:
number:

the user taps a block and then then selects a contact.

[image]

At the moment I can populate one of the blocks with the name and number the user selects from the contacts list.

here is the relevant code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Contacts, Contact, ContactField, ContactName } from '@ionic-native/contacts/ngx';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-component',
  templateUrl: './contact-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-component.component.scss'],
})
export class ContactComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private contacts: Contacts) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {}
  cName:any;
  cNumber:any;
  pickContact() {
    this.contacts.pickContact().then((contact) => {
    this.cName = contact.name.givenName;
    this.cNumber = contact.phoneNumbers[0].value;
      // console.log(cNumber);
    });
  }
}
```

here is the hmtl
which is repeated 5 times to make 5 blocks

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item-group (click) = "pickContact()">
          <ion-card>
              <ion-item lines = "none">             
                  <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Name: {{cName}}</ion-label>        
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item lines = "none" >
                  <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Number: {{cNumber}}</ion-label>
                </ion-item>       
          </ion-card>            
        </ion-item-group>
```

my problem is I do not know how to repeat this, without having piles of code.

I was thinking of using a nested Array but I am not sure entirely how to go about it
I want the user to tap on a block -> select a contact -> functions populates corresponding block.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is exceptional at handling lists. Indeed, you do not have to hardcode the whole list.

What you need is the ***ngFor** directive.

**.html file**

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let contact of emergencyContacts; let i=index">
    <ion-item-group (click)="pickContact(i)">
        <ion-item lines = "none">             
            <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Name: {{contact.name}}</ion-label>        
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item lines = "none" >
          <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Number: {{contact.number}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>  
    </ion-item-group>     
</ion-card>
```

**.ts file**

```
export class ContactComponentComponent implements OnInit {

/*
of course, the following array would be better to be created by a loop
I leave it this way to be easier to understand
*/
      emergencyContacts = [
        {name: '', number: ''},
        {name: '', number: ''},
        {name: '', number: ''},
        {name: '', number: ''},
        {name: '', number: ''}
      ]

      constructor(private contacts: Contacts) { }

      ngOnInit() {}

      pickContact(i) {
          this.contacts.pickContact().then((contact) => {
              this.emergencyContacts[i].name = contact.name.givenName;
              this.emergencyContacts[i].number = contact.phoneNumbers[0].value;
          });
      }
}
```